# Process multiple records, one at a time, with same form

Tags: yii, multiple-records

I have a table that contains multiple records for the same user (each record is slightly different - for a reason).
I need to be able to edit each record, one at a time, using a standard Yii form.

I've tried the following code but I need it to wait for each form to be submitted before the loop continues to display the form for the next record. At the moment, it displays the form for each record, all at once, on one page.

I'm sure I figured out how to do it once many, many projects ago but I can't remember what I did to get it to work right :(

```
public function actionProcess()
{
    $system = get some data;

    foreach ($system as $item):
        $this->getExperience($item);
    endforeach;
}

protected function getExperience($item)
{
    $model = get data for the form

    if(isset($_POST['the_form'])):
        $model->attributes=$_POST['the_form'];
        if($model->save())
            return true;
    endif;

    $this->render('the_form', array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

Comment: add the pointer of the loop as a hidden input in your form and on each POST do +1 on the pointer and show the next record ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. I figured out my own solution which I'll share for the benefit of others:

```
$_stack = array(); // defined in the Class global space

public function actionProcess()
{
    $system = get some data

    foreach ($system as $item):
        $this->_stack[] = $item->id;
    endforeach;

    if(!empty($this->_stack))
        $this->getExperience();
}

protected function getExperience()
{
    if(empty($this->_stack))
        $this->redirect(array('somewhere else'));

    $model = get data for the form using $_stack[0] as the reference for what to obtain

    if(isset($_POST['the_form'])):
        $model->attributes=$_POST['the_form'];

        if($model->save()):
            array_shift($this->_stack);
            $this->getExperience();
        endif;
    endif;

$this->render('the_form', array('model'=>$model,));
}
```